# Convergent Subsequence Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Prove that:

1. $x_n = 2\sin^3(n) + 6\cos^5(2n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

I understand the concept of a convergent subsequence. 
If someone could explain to me if there is a proper way of proving this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of sequences do you know that have convergent subsequences?

Comment: If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of reals then by Bolzano-Weierstress theorem it has a convergent subsequence

Answer (score 2):

Since $|x_n|\le 8$ for all $n$, the sequence is contained in a compact subset of $\Bbb R$.  Hence, it must have a limit point, and therefore a convergent subsequence.

Comment: In a nutshell: compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness in metric spaces.